# Algorithm for converting integers into strings over a given alphabet

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to implement an algorithm which converts artibrary long, non-negative integers to strings of a given alphabet A and of length k and in bigendian byteorder:

[image]

where

[image]

My code:

```
def ToString(x, k, A):       
    S = []
    N = len(A)  # N = |A|

    for i in reversed(range(0,k)):
        s_k = InverseRank(x % N,A,N,k,i)
        x = x // N
        S.insert(0,s_k)

    return S

def InverseRank(x,A,N,k,i):
    return A[(x//N**(k-i-1)) % N]
```

However, it's not working correctly.

```
  A = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']   # Alphabet
  k = 3
  x = 123
  S = ToString(x,k,A)
```

results in:

```
  s => ['A', 'A', 'E']
```

No matter what x I choose, the resulting string only differs in the last character. The first two are always 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the "where" explanation.
The expression
[image: S_Expression]
is what the function's algorithm is supposed to generate and not the rank function to be used itself in your line `s_k = InverseRank(x % N,A,N,k,i)`.

One solution is to change your `s_k = InverseRank(x % N,A,N,k,i)` into `s_k = A[x % N]`.